# How to add the phrase in order to specify something?

Tags: word-usage, difference, grammaticality-in-context

Base sentence: I defined A.

I want to add the contents that "A is useful"

Of course, there are so many ways to imply that contents.

But, I want to know what the difference is or ask if each sentence is correct or not.

> candidate 1.  I defined A *as being useful.*
>
> candidate 2.  I defined A *to be useful.*

Comment: Welcome ian, would you please tell us what you want to convey by those sentences? Honestly, as a learner, I'm not sure if I understood your sentences completely. Why would you want to use the verb "define"?

Comment: Both sentences are correct but have different meanings.  Some context for these sentences would be useful.

Comment: @Cardinal Oh, actually, when I saw the lecture via Youtube, the lecturer uses the sentence "We defined function spaces as being useful in order to give us ...". So I just would like to know why he uses the expression "as being".

Answer (score 1):

Candidate 1 is not normal English, and a native speaker would not use "as being" in this case, unless you meant "I defined A as 'being useful'", so that for example "I am A" means "I am being useful", but I don't think that's what you mean. If it is, please say so.

Candidate 2 claims "I defined A, and had the intention that it would be useful".

If you'd rather claim that A *is* useful, rather than that it was *intended* to be useful, as you suggest in your question, I would say "I defined A usefully", claiming that A is defined in a useful manner.

You could also say something more similar to "I defined a useful A", calling A useful with an adjective, which would probably be more natural, but I cannot give a specific example that would work without more context.

"I defined A, which is useful" would also be correct, albeit a bit clunky.

If you gave some more context, I could perhaps answer your question better.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N5YSuBZMZM&list=PLJhG_d-Sp_JHKVRhfTgDqbic_4MHpltXZ&index=16)

Above the link, (0:33~), the lecturer uses the similar sentence. As I am a non-native speaker, I want to know how to make the "long" English sentence. Your answer really helps me. Thanks.